# How can I 301 redirect a page URL on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, google-app-engine-python

I am updating the file structure of my hand coded static site, as I originally created it a while back when I had less of an appreciation of best practices for file structure in web development.

I am aware that for best user experience, as well as optimal SEO purposes, redirects should be used minimally.

I have searched Stack Overflow and Google in general for a solution for setting up 301 redirects for individual static page URL's on Google App Engine (GAE), however I only seem to be able to find entire domain name redirect explinations.

The site is hand coded in html, css and js with Bootstrap v3.3.7 integrated for mobile responsiveness.

The site is hosted on Google App Engine and is a subdomain of .appspot.com (http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com).

I will be for example moving the following page:

http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html

to the new URL:

http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html

still under http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/

My **app.yaml** is as follows:

```
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /
   static_files: www/index.html
   upload: www/index.html

 - url: /(.*)
   static_files: www/\1
   upload: www/(.*)
```

My **main.py** file is as follows:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

If scripting is required I would prefer to implement a python solution as that is the current deployment on GAE.

Don't hesitate to ask if I have missed out any vital information.

Thanks in advance for your response.

---

**UPDATE**

I have now tried editing my main.py file to introduce a self.redirect as follows:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    if q = 'content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html':
      redirect_url = 'http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html'
      self.redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)         

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))  

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

However this did not work. When visiting the url http://www.christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html I am not redirected and instead get Error: **Not Found
The requested URL /content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html was not found on this server.**

I have also tried:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'      

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))  

    if q = 'content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html':
      redirect_url = 'http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html'
      self.redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)       

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

As well as ...

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'      

    if q = 'content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html':
      redirect_url = 'scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html'
      self.redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)        

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))       

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have provided a screenshot below of my current main.py file:

[screenshot of main.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsf1r.jpg)

---

**UPDATE 3**

My latest main.py file:

[latest screenshot of main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zGDQ.png)

The logs:

[screenshot of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDOMZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `self.redirect` built right into `webapp`.  Add this to your `def get(self, q)`:

```
logging.info(q)

if q == 'content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html':

    redirect_url = 'http://christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html'

    self.redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)
```

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I have tried this for a number of hours with no success. As a test I have moved the page to http://www.christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html which works, but when you type in http://www.christopher-john-roberts.appspot.com/content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html you are not redirected to the first url. I have updated with original question above with variations I have tried.

Comment: That should be a double equals sign `==` in `if q == 'content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html':`  Log q to see what its current value is at that url.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had also tried with the double equals sign after I commented. The live version now has `if q == 'content/scientific-skills/mres-post-genomic-science.html':` however it is still not working. I am unsure how to "Log q to see what its current value is at that url". I am only used to logging in JavaScript. I have added `import logging` after `import os` and added `logging.warning(q) ` after `self.redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)` but I don't see anything.

Comment: I have provided a screenshot of the main.py file at the bottom of the above question in an update

Comment: The `logging` needs to be outside the conditional.  Else, you already know what it is.  See update.  Check your logs at:  https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=christopher-john-roberts

Comment: I have now amended the logging to outside the conditional as suggested, and checked the logs (provided as a screenshot in the main question above). The first log shows accessing the page in the new directory working. The second log is when I try to access at the old address. If I move the html file back to the old location it opens, so it appears to be ignoring the redirect. I also tried redirecting to the homepage, but again this was ignored.

Comment: Your `logging.info` isn't showing up.  Make sure you set minimum logging to view info, or change your code to `logging.error(q)` so it stands out